# External drive not appearing in "Disks"

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, usb-drive

A few years I encased an HDD in an 'inateck 2.5" SATA HDD External Enclosure'. I was able to access the files in this drive on Windows at the time. Now, using Ubuntu, I am unable to find the drive using the "Disks" application when it is plugged in via USB and turned on. It is also not visible in the Nautilus file browser.

Why is this? I know the computer is seeing something. Running the command `sudo dmesg | tail -16` returns the following:

```
[410544.610774] usb 3-5: new high-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
[410544.759198] usb 3-5: New USB device found, idVendor=2537, idProduct=1066, bcdDevice= 1.00
[410544.759208] usb 3-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[410544.759212] usb 3-5: Product: NS1066
[410544.759215] usb 3-5: Manufacturer: Norelsys
[410544.759217] usb 3-5: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDE
[410544.760661] usb-storage 3-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[410544.761364] scsi host1: usb-storage 3-5:1.0
[410547.897361] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NORELSYS 106X             0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[410547.897965] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[410547.898377] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[410547.899225] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[410547.899234] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[410547.899677] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[410548.033030]  sda: sda1 sda2
[410548.083654] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

`sudo lsblk` returns the following (also does not show the newly connected drive):

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0           7:0    0  43.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/15177
loop1           7:1    0  55.5M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2344
loop2           7:2    0 215.4M  1 loop  /snap/blender/2106
loop3           7:3    0  44.7M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/15534
sda             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0   200M  0 part  
└─sda2          8:2    0 931.2G  0 part  
nvme0n1       259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0     4G  0 part  /recovery
├─nvme0n1p3   259:3    0   923G  0 part  /
└─nvme0n1p4   259:4    0     4G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap 253:0    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

Why can't I access the files on the drive? Why can't I even see the drive?

Thanks, and best regards.

Comment: A few questions: (1) What file system is being used on the external disk? (2) Is the disk encrypted? (3) Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk`? (4) Do you want to regain access to the data on the disk, or do you want to wipe the disk to use it as a "fresh" storage device? With this, it may be possible to offer a solution. 

Comment: (1) I am not sure and I don't know how to find that out since the drive appears to not be showing up in the filesystem.
(2) The disk is not encrypted
(3) Done
(4) I want to regain access to the data on the disk.

Comment: Are you sure `lsblk` is not showing the newly-connected storage device? Your `dmsg` output reports `sda` is connected, and `lsblk` shows two partitions on the device 

Comment: Ah, you are right. Disconnecting removes the sda drives from `lsblk`. I am sorry. The internal and external drives are so similar in size I must have thought that they were the same. It is also showing up on "Disks". Sorry. Both are 1 TB.

Comment: Anyway, how do I gain access to the data? I suppose I have more to work with now and I can find the answer somewhere else online.

Comment: If these are NTFS partitions, it would be *safer* to first confirm the partitions are okay via Windows. If you don't have a Windows machine to test with, you can get a [90-day virtual machine from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). Run `chkdsk` from Windows and make sure the partition is okay. Then make sure you "Safe Eject" the disk to ensure the partition is not left in an open state. From there, you should be able to access the disk normally in Ubuntu 